# std::getline fails after SSL function calls

Tags: c++, ssl, cin, getline

My `getline` read loop has stopped reading input after calls to some SSL functions.  Previously I had:

```
std::string input;
...

while (std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
  ...
}
```

This worked fine.  But after I wrapped the socket with SSL, input from the console is no longer being read.

```
SSL* ssl_fd = SSL_new(ctx);
if (NULL == ssl_fd) {
  close(new_fd);
  continue;
}

if (0 == SSL_set_fd(ssl_fd, new_fd)) {
  close(new_fd);
  continue;
}

if (1 != SSL_accept(ssl_fd)) {
  ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
  close(new_fd);
  continue;
}

while (std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
  ...
}
```

I've tried adding some calls to clear any buffer issues (`std::cout << std::flush`, `std::cin.ignore()`, `std::cin.clear()`), but at this point I'm out of ideas.  It's really weird; if I take out the SSL calls, then the read loop runs fine and processes the input correctly.  As far as I can tell, the SSL calls don't have any impact on stdin or stdout.

Any recommendations or alternate approaches I could try?

Comment: Wrapped _what_ socket? Can't you present a complete testcase? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve You were informed about all of this when you signed up a moment ago.

Comment: I harbor suspicions that your code which obtains that socket is smashing your stack. Send this through valgrind.